# Read what others wrote to standard out

Tags: java

I want to read what gets written to stdout in a Java process that spawns other processes using inheritIO. **I cannot use redirectOut** as I have no control over the code that starts the process!. Also note that **resetting System.setOut doesn't work** in this case.
Also I don't have access to the Process object.

Example:

```
new ProcessBuilder().command('/bin/echo', 'FooBar').inheritIO.start
// read 'FooBar' from standard out
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, inheritIO causes the output of subprocess to be the same of the output of caller. So as soon as you call it on the ProcessBuilder, the calling process **cannot** read the standard output nor error streams of the callee.

As you say you cannot change that, the only way I can imagine is to use an external launcher that redirects output to a pipe (the default for ProcessBuilder...), starts the program containing the line you showed (`new ProcessBuilder().command('/bin/echo', 'FooBar').inheritIO.start`) and processes that output.